# How to go through each element in a for a loop C++ using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a string of names

It holds ["John Doe","Patrick", "Star", "Sandy Cheeks"]

How would I access each letter of the array using a for loop? So let's say I wanted to access the "J" in Jonh Doe all the way to the "s" in Sandy Cheeks?

**I can only use the library iostream and string**

Comment: Please show in code how your `std::string` of names is declared and initialized.

Comment: "I have a string of names" - names are strings. what you need is an array of strings. Each individual element in an array can be access by [ ] operator. string also supports accessing individual characters by [ ] operator.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 you can achieve this easily by using a range-based for loop like so:

```
std::string arr[] = {"John Doe","Patrick", "Star", "Sandy Cheeks"};

for(const std::string& str : arr)
{
  for(const char& chr : str)
  {
    //use chr
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more explicit method:

```
static const std::string people[] = {"John Doe", "Patrick", "Star", "Sandy Cheeks"};
size_t name_quantity = sizeof(people) / sizeof(people[0]);
for (size_t name_index = 0; name_index < name_quantity; ++name_index)
{
  const std::string& name(people[name_index]);
  const size_t name_length = name.length();
  for (size_t letter_index = 0; letter_index < name_length; ++letter_index)
  {
    char letter = name[letter_index];
    Process_Letter(letter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a string of names, you have a array of strings, in c++11 you can use a rang based for loop

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "-HW-" << std::endl;

    std::string names[] =
    { "John Doe", "Patrick", "Star", "Sandy Cheeks" };

    for (const auto& x : names)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```